# How do i save each line of the file to an Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I tried the method posted below but still no success. I get an error of cannot find symbol. How else can i modify the code below. Do i have to place the line in the bottom?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
/**
 * Write a description of class lab8 here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class lab8
{
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
   FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("haikuFun.txt");
   Scanner scrn = new Scanner(fileIn);
   String[] lines = fileIn.readAllLines(new File("haikuFun.txt").toPath());
   while(scrn.hasNext()) {
     String s = scrn.nextLine();
     System.out.println(s);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: It'll be easier to use an ArrayList.

Comment: My instructor hasnt taught us how to use an Array list. I really cant use that

Comment: Do you know how many lines there are?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read text file into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257981/read-text-file-into-an-array)

Comment: @shmosel there are a total of six lines.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`Files.readAllLines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) like

```
String[] lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("haikuFun.txt").toPath());
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple one line solution using Java 8

```
String[] lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("somefile.txt")).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: I am sorry but what is "Paths" used for

Comment: I tried to use it and it shows an error which is "cannot find symbol - variable Paths

Comment: use import java.nio.file.Paths; It is a java class

Comment: Hey now i am getting a error stating that "toArray" is not applicable

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Files.readAllLines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) like

```
String[] lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("haikuFun.txt"));
```

But in case you have a huge file, you could have a problem. In this case, you could use Stream:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("haikuFun.txt"))) {
    stream.forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```